# Find $y$ such that $x^*$ is a global maximizer of $f(x,y)$.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose I have a continuously differentiable function $f(x,y)$ with respect to both arguments. For some $y$, $x^* = \arg\max_{x} f(x,y)$.

Now, I know the $x^*$ value and I want to know if $y$ that supports $x^*$ is unique or not. What would be sufficient conditions to have a unique $y$.

Comment: Does the function $f$ possesses some concavity properties?

Comment: @gerw Actually this is what I want to know -- under what shape of  $f$, I have unique $y$. Maybe $f$ could be concave.